# Handwritten numbers recognition model not functioning as expected

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, mnist

Basically I'm trying to teach myself machine learning with the aid of chatgpt, and I started with the basic 3blue1brown youtube channel's example that builds a model and trains it over the mnist dataset of handwritten digits.
Then I wanted to take it a bit further such that instead of recognizing a single digit image from the same mnist dataset, it should simply look at any image of my handwriting (a white background with a number written) with multidigit numbers and figure out what those are but it's far from accurate; though the accuracy after 100 epochs of training was 99.2% and it figures out the number of digits in the image.
Here's the model:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import cv2

# Load the MNIST dataset
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.mnist.load_data()

# Normalize the pixel values
x_train = x_train / 255.0
x_test = x_test / 255.0

# Define the neural network architecture
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(100) # 100 neurons for double digit output
])

# Compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the model
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100)

# Load an image and convert it to grayscale
image_path = r'G:\Dr. Thrax\1MAC\PYTHON\Tinkering with python coding\Data_sources\AI_Test\0007.jpeg'
image = cv2.imread(image_path)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
#gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)

# Apply binary thresholding to the image to separate digits from the background
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours in the image
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Sort contours from left to right
contours = sorted(contours, key=lambda c: cv2.boundingRect(c)[0])

# Create a list to hold the digit images
digits = []

# Iterate over the contours
for contour in contours:
    # Get the bounding box of the contour
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    # Extract the digit image
    digit = thresh[y:y+h, x:x+w]

    # Resize the digit image to 28x28
    digit = cv2.resize(digit, (28, 28))

    # Add the digit image to the list
    digits.append(digit)

# Create a list to hold the predictions
predictions = []

# Iterate over the digit images
for digit in digits:
    # Reshape the digit image to (1, 28, 28, 1)
    digit = digit.reshape(1, 28, 28, 1)

    # Make a prediction on the digit image
    pred = model.predict(digit)

    # Get the digit prediction
    digit_pred = np.argmax(pred)

    # Add the digit prediction to the list
    predictions.append(digit_pred)

# Combine the digit predictions to get the final number
number = 0
for pred in predictions:
    number = number * 10 + pred

# Plot the image and the prediction
plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
plt.title(f'Prediction: {number}')
plt.show()
```

I tried the following:

- changing the number of training epochs,
- changing the number of layers,
- Alternating between sigmoid and softmax functions for the last layer
  but no luck in getting the prediction anywhere near the right answer, though it recognizes the number of digits in the image almost correctly. Can any body point out to me what I'm doing wrong, or what should I do to improve it?

Comment: MNIST is an academic dataset, it is not meant to be used for real-world applications, so it is not reasonable to expect real images to work on a classifier trained using this dataset.

Comment: Also I think you are not normalizing (/ 255.0) your new images, that is definitely an issue that would make the model predict incorrectly.